# Blur sensitive text in pdf

Tags: java, python, opencv, pdf

I want to blur sensitive information in pdf file. I read about pyPdf in python and PDFBox of java but I could not get how to search and replace text in pdf file. By replacing I mean blur or even asterik character. 
I also thought of a step in which I can take image of very page of pdf and then show them in html one by one. But then the same problem is there how to replace text in those images?

Comment: I removed the `c++` and `java` tags, left the `python` one since it's been at least mentioned once.

Comment: *Searching and replacing text in a pdf file* is non-trivial to implement for generic documents. If, on the other hand, a solution would suffice which removes PDF instructions drawing anything in certain *regions* (given by rectangle coordinates and dimensions) and then blackens them, then you might be interested in the [pdfSweep](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfsweep) iText / Java add-on.

Comment: The Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit can do redaction. I've found it to be more reliable that PDFSweep in finding and correctly locating the redaction marks.